# SQL Server backup fails when issued via PDO

Tags: sql-server, pdo, database-backups

I'm talking to an SQL server 2005 using PHP's PDO API:

```
$mssql = new PDO('dblib:host=foohost;dbname=foodb', 'foouser', 'foopassword');
```

Subsequently, I want to backup the database to a local file as shown in the code below - which then fails.

```
$query = "
    BACKUP DATABASE foodb
        TO DISK = 'D:\\migration\\test_backup.bak';
    GO
";
$stmt = $mssql->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

The error I'm getting is this (result from `$stmt->errorInfo()`):

```
[0] => HY000
[1] => 102
[2] => General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [102] (severity 15) [(null)]
[3] => -1
[4] => 15
```

I've tried to do the same thing using SQL Server Management Studio, and the exact same query works. So - any hints on how I could get this to work (Note: I'm forced to use PHP on a remote linux host, so any local windows tools won't work)

Comment: Did you try putting the command in a stored procedure, and calling the stored procedure from PHP?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, As far as I understand, this would only shift the problem to the creation of said procedure. It won't be possible to automate. However I'll look into it.

Comment: Well you can pass any arguments you want into the stored procedure. You might get a more meaningful error message, or you might actually avoid the error altogether if it's breaking because PDO has no idea how parse a backup command...